# Using component dynamically for different views

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What I want to achieve is the following:

I have a Layout with the following parts:

- Header
- Main (here various views are loaded based on the route where you are, in this example just Account.vue)
- Footer

Example route: localhost:8080/account (It will load: Account.vue)

In this route I want to load a component called: Section.vue. This will be html code with various DIV blocks: a header, content and footer structure.

```
<template>
    <div class="header">{{ Title }}</div>
    <div class="main">{{ Form or anything else }}</main>
    <div class="footer">{{ Save Button }}</footer>
</template>
```

My idea is to be able to manage this block in 1 place in terms of styling. (So in Section.vue). So if I make an adjustment in terms of design, everything will be applied immediately where Secton.vue is loaded. This saves me a lot of work. I want to dynamically supplement the content of this block with Account.vue with a title in the header. In the content a form with various fields and in the footer a save button.

The only problem I run into now. Where do I start to get this done?

I want to load Section.vue getting loaded into Account.vue as I need it there and want to fill this component with some header, content en footer things which are nessecary for the view of Account.vue

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but if I understand you correctly maybe vue slot will help you achieve your goal.
Here is the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html